# On the interpretation of distributiveness

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 1. The two of us ordered a hamburger.
> 2. We ordered a hamburger.

Do these and the like mean each of us ordered a hamburger or we together ordered a hamburger,  or maybe both are possible depending on the context？

What would you say if you want to convey one of these specific meanings?  Thanks.

Comment: It would be *normal* to use plural ***hamburgers*** rather than singular ***a hamburger*** in both your examples, UNLESS you actually intended to convey that you two ***shared*** a single hamburger. But if you *did* intend that relatively unlikely sense, other parts of the context would almost certainly make that blindingly obvious. OR you as the speaker / writer should have sense enough to realise what you're saying might not be understood correctly, so you should rephrase. I think this question is "frivolously vexatious"

Comment: @FumbleFingers  But the plural hamburgers would only say what kind of food we have ordered, without mentioning the number.  Can I rephrase it as:  We **both** ordered a hamburger.  I feel that the both implies distributiveness

Comment: **Each** would be better than **both**.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. My first comment notwithstanding, as soon as you include ***each***, it becomes perfectly natural to use the ***singular***. Unless you're big eaters - ***We each ordered three hamburgers*** unambiguously states that we ordered ***six*** in total. Some people might understand ***both*** as having the same implication, but personally I might not, so if it mattered I'd probably ask you to clarify what you meant.